# mod_rewrite changing /subpage/ to /subpage

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

Okey, so this is my problem.
I want to use mod_rewrite to make nice looking urls for my site.

I want them all to have good looking url like www.mypage/tennis or www.mypage/soccer instead of www.mypage/?page=tennis and www.mypage/?page=soccer

And with the following rules i can achive this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

So now if I type in www.mypage/soccer my PHP script reads this url and does it's magic translating this to $_GET['page'] = soccer. All this works fine!

**Problem is** if I would type the URL **www.mypage/soccer/** all of a sudden every linked css or image cannot be found by the website, since it now looking in the none existing folder **/soccer/** off course.

How do I make a rewrite rule that transforms **/soccer/** to **/soccer** or any other /blabla/ to /blabla

Hope my question is clear! Also if anyone have any good pages where I can learn more regular expressions i would be very happy!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ty! That works... still does not really answer my core question; Is it possible to remove the ending / on any url?

Comment: This only works if i use absolute path or set a base for my website. Is there a way without that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use `mod_rewrite` for this, but rather fix your CSS and image paths.

Change the paths from [*relative to absolute*](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm),
meaning, the paths should begin with a `/`.

If you have this, no matter on which site your are, `/images/myimage.png` will always refer to  `www.mypage.com/images/myimage.png`.

Comment: Off course that is one solution. But, let's say i still want to keep my relative paths, there must be a way to rewrite any /sub/ to /sub which works even without absolute paths.

Comment: And yet another solution is to just add; <base href="http://mypage.com/"> and we have set out base for all links in the site. But i want to do it with mod_rewrite :D

Comment: @jamietelin: Ah true... nice :) But why add unnecessary server side processing, if the solution can be so simple?

Comment: Cause knowledge is king :) I simply want to know. Also it has to do with portable coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
#  For URIs with query string:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*)/$ ?page=$1&%1 [L]

#  All other

RewriteRule (.*)/$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: In what way is this different than what Brian H wrote? (sorry I am not very good at mod_rewrite or regex)