# Problems with mod_rewrite and GET

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, get

So, I had a question earlier about mod_rewrite which you find here [mod_rewrite changing /subpage/ to /subpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326212/mod-rewrite-changing-subpage-to-subpage)

But now I have a whole new problem with this... How do I make GET work?

Like if I need to pass some variables with GET, ex: mypage.com/subpage/?name=Jamie

My mod_rewrite looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L]
```

I understand that the problem probably has to do with that I already pass and rewrite one GET request. So how do i tweak this to accept any other GET-request i might need to process?

***UPDATE:***
To clarify the problem a bit. If I try the url **mypage.com/subpage/?name=Jamie** page loads as if i used url **mypage.com/subpage/** and "name" is never passed. Using my original url **mypage.com?p=subpage&name=Jamie** works as it should.

I guess i need to tweak this somehow... but how?
Thank you for taking your time reading my probably easy question!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Well, if I try the url mypage.com/subpage/?name=Jamie page loads as if i used url mypage.com/subpage/ and name is never passed, at leat it seems like. Using my original url mypage.com?p=subpage&name=Jamie works as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `QSA` flag — [Query String Append](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> `'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)`
>   This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/\?$ ?p=$1 [L]
```

as '?' is a meta character in regex, it needs to be escaped

Comment: adding the \ makes it not work at all, then all I get is page doesn't exist. The original request works fine, but I cant pass any more Get-requests i seems like.